# Realizar un Update de base de datos desde MVC en PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server, ajax

Ahora tengo mi código de la siguiente manera, realicé las modificaciones mencionadas pero aún sigue sin reflejar ningún cambio y, al parecer, arroja que **data** se encuentra vacío, siendo que el arreglo que envío si contiene la información que cargo desde mi tabla al dar doble clic en una de las filas.

Tengo otra función que se encarga de cargar campos con opciones múltiples y si funciona, al dar doble clic, busca el campo que quiero cargar y además me arroja las demás opciones que se encuentran en ese campo.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "app/controllers/Nivscontroller/nivController.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                actualizarDatos: true,
                folio: Edicionfolio,
                NombreE: EdicionNombre,
                FechaDocE: EdicionFechaDoc,
                CorporacionE: EdicionCorporacion,
                FechaRegistroE: EdicionFechaRegistro,
            

    DocumentoE: EdicionDocumento,
            DocumentoRecibidoE: EdicionDocumentoRecibido,
            FechadeRegistroE: EdicionFechadeRegistro,
            DependenciaE: EdicionDependencia,
            MunicipioE: EdicionMunicipio,
            SiteE: EdicionSite,
            TurnadoAE: EdicionTurnadoA,
            ObservacionesE: EdicionObservaciones,
        },

        success: function(data) {
          console.log("Respuesta completa del servidor:", data);
          if (data.status) {
            alert("Datos actualizados correctamente", data.msg);
              $("#Edición").modal("hide");
              table.ajax.reload(); // Recargar la tabla
          } else {
              alert("No fue posible actualizar los datos. "+data.msg);
              console.log("Mensajes de error:", data.msg);
          }
        },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.error("Error en la solicitud de actualización:", errorThrown);
          console.log("jqXHR:", jqXHR.responseText);
          console.log("textStatus:", textStatus);
        },
    });
    }
  });
```

Y este otro de acá es mi Modelo:

```
public static function actualizarFila($folio, $EdicionNombre, $EdicionFechaDoc,$EdicionCorporacion, $EdicionFechaRegistro,
    $EdicionDocumento, $EdicionDocumentoRecibido, $EdicionFechadeRegistro, $EdicionDependencia, $EdicionMunicipio, $EdicionSite, 
    $EdicionTurnadoA, $EdicionObservaciones) 
{
    try 
    {
        include '../../../config/conexion.php';
        $consulta = "UPDATE OprCorrespodencia 
        SET Nombre = :EdicionNombre, FechaDocuemntoRecibido = :EdicionFechaDoc, Corporacion = :EdicionCorporacion, 
        FechaRegistro = :EdicionFechaRegistro, Documento = :EdicionDocumento, DocumentoRecibido = :EdicionDocumentoRecibido,
        FechadeRegistro = :EdicionFechadeRegistro, Dependencia = :EdicionDependencia, Municipio = :EdicionMunicipio, 
        Site = :EdicionSite, TurnadoA = :EdicionTurnadoA, Observaciones = :EdicionObservaciones WHERE folio = :folio";
        
        $stmt = $connect->prepare($consulta);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionNombre', $EdicionNombre, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionFechaDoc', $EdicionFechaDoc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionCorporacion', $EdicionCorporacion, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionFechaRegistro', $EdicionFechaRegistro, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionDocumento', $EdicionDocumento, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionDocumentoRecibido', $EdicionDocumentoRecibido, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionFechadeRegistro', $EdicionFechadeRegistro, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionDependencia', $EdicionDependencia, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionMunicipio', $EdicionMunicipio, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionSite', $EdicionSite, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionTurnadoA', $EdicionTurnadoA, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionObservaciones', $EdicionObservaciones, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
        $stmt->bindParam(':folio', $folio, PDO::PARAM_STR);     
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->rowCount()>0) 
        {
            $outPut=array('status'=>true, 'msg'=>sprintf('Filas actualizadas: %d',$stmt->rowCount()));
        } 
        else 
        {
            $outPut=array('status'=>false, 'msg'=>"No hubo error de código, pero el criterio $folio no se cumple");
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        $outPut=array('status'=>false, 'msg'=>sprintf('Error!: %s',$stmt->errorInfo()[2]));
    } 
    finally 
    {
        return $outPut;
    }
}
```

Este es todo mi Controlador

```
<?php

    class NivController{

        public function CargarTabla($niv,$Idusuario){

            include '../../models/NivsModel/nivModel.php';
            echo NivModel::cargarRegistros($Idusuario);
        }
        public function CargaFolio(){
            include '../../models/NivsModel/nivModel.php';
            return NivModel::CargaFolio();
        }
        public function CargaDependencias(){
            include '../../models/NivsModel/nivModel.php';
            return NivModel::CargaDependencias();
        }
        public function CargaCorporacion(){
            include '../../models/NivsModel/nivModel.php';
            return NivModel::CargaCorporacion();
        }
        public function CargaMunicipios(){
            include '../../models/NivsModel/nivModel.php';
            return NivModel::CargaMunicipios();
        }
        public function CargaSitio(){
            include '../../models/NivsModel/nivModel.php';
            return NivModel::CargaSitio();
        }
        public function TurnadoA(){
            include '../../models/NivsModel/nivModel.php';
            return NivModel::TurnadoA();
        }
        public function InsertarDatosNIV($Marca,$submarca,$clase,$tipo,$fabrica,$pais,$nivSelect,$IdNiv,$IdUsuario){
            include '../../models/NivsModel/nivModel.php';
            return NivModel::InsertarDatosNIV($Marca,$submarca,$clase,$tipo,$fabrica,$pais,$nivSelect,$IdNiv,$IdUsuario);
        }
        public function InsertarCorrespondencia($Folio, $FechaRegistro, $DocumentoRecibido, $FechaDocumento, $fechaREcibido, $NumOficio, $Remitente, $Dependencia, $Corporacion, $Municipio, $site, $turnado, $Observaciones) {
            include '../../models/NivsModel/nivModel.php';
            return NivModel::InsertarCorrespondencia($Folio, $FechaRegistro, $DocumentoRecibido, $FechaDocumento, $fechaREcibido, $NumOficio, $Remitente, $Dependencia, $Corporacion, $Municipio, $site, $turnado, $Observaciones);
        }
    }

    $actualizarDatos = true;
    $messages = [];

    if (strpos(file_get_contents('php://input'), 'niv: 1') !== false) {
        // Manejar caso especial si 'niv: 1' está presente

        $isUpdate=$_POST['actualizarDatos'] ?? NULL;
        if ($isUpdate) 
        {
            // Obtener datos del formulario
            $EdicionNombre = $_POST['NombreE'] ?? NULL;
            $EdicionFechaDoc = $_POST['FechaDocE'] ?? NULL;
            $EdicionCorporacion = $_POST['CorporacionE'] ?? NULL;
            $EdicionFechaRegistro = $_POST['FechaRegistroE'] ?? NULL;
            $EdicionDocumento = $_POST['DocumentoE'] ?? NULL;
            $EdicionDocumentoRecibido = $_POST['DocumentoRecibidoE'] ?? NULL;
            $EdicionFechadeRegistro = $_POST['FechadeRegistroE'] ?? NULL;
            $EdicionDependencia = $_POST['DependenciaE'] ?? NULL;
            $EdicionMunicipio = $_POST['MunicipioE'] ?? NULL;
            $EdicionSite = $_POST['SiteE'] ?? NULL;
            $EdicionTurnadoA = $_POST['TurnadoAE'] ?? NULL;
            $EdicionObservaciones = $_POST['ObservacionesE'] ?? NULL;
            $folio = $_POST['folio'] ?? NULL;
        // Si todos los datos son válidos, intentar actualizar
            require_once '../../models/NivsModel/nivModel.php';
        
            // Realizar la actualización en la base de datos
            $outPut = NivModel::actualizarFila($EdicionNombre, $EdicionFechaDoc, $EdicionCorporacion, $EdicionFechaRegistro,
            $EdicionDocumento, $EdicionDocumentoRecibido, $EdicionFechadeRegistro, $EdicionDependencia, $EdicionMunicipio, $EdicionSite, 
            $EdicionTurnadoA, $EdicionObservaciones, $folio);
        } 
        else 
        {
            $outPut=array('status'=>false, 'msg'=>'No se eligió la opción de actualizar');
        }
        
        header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
        echo json_encode($outPut);
        exit();
    }

    if (isset($_POST['obtenerInfoAdicional'])) {
       
        // Obtén los datos necesarios
        $municipio = $_POST['municipio'];
        $dependencia = $_POST['dependencia'];
        $turnado = $_POST['turnado'];
        $site = $_POST['site'];

        try {
            require_once '../../models/NivsModel/nivModel.php';
            // Realiza la lógica para obtener información adicional
            $infoAdicional = NivModel::obtenerOpcionesMultiples($municipio, $dependencia, $turnado, $site);
               
            // Devuelve la información adicional como JSON
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($infoAdicional);
            exit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode(['error' => 'Error interno del servidor: ' . $e->getMessage()]);
            exit();
        }
    }
    
    if(isset($_POST["Folio2"])) {
    $Folio = $_POST["Folio2"];
    $FechaRegistro = $_POST["FechaRegistro"];
    $DocumentoRecibido = $_POST["DocumentoRecibido"];
    $FechaDocumento = $_POST["FechaDocumento"];
    $fechaREcibido = $_POST["fechaREcibido"];
    $NumOficio = $_POST["NumOficio"];
    $Remitente = $_POST["Remitente"];
    $Dependencia = $_POST["Dependencia"];
    $Corporacion = $_POST["Corporacion"];
    $Municipio = $_POST["Municipio"];
    $site = $_POST["Site"];
    $turnado = $_POST["TurnadoA"];
    $Observaciones = $_POST["Observaciones"];
    
    $control = new NivController();
    echo $control->InsertarCorrespondencia($Folio, $FechaRegistro, $DocumentoRecibido, $FechaDocumento, $fechaREcibido, $NumOficio, $Remitente, $Dependencia, $Corporacion, $Municipio, $site, $turnado, $Observaciones);
    }

 
    if(isset($_POST["niv"])) {
        session_start();
        $IdUsuario =$_SESSION["id_usuario"];
            $control = new NivController();
         echo   $control->CargarTabla($_POST["niv"],$IdUsuario);
         
    }
    if(isset($_POST["Folio"])) {
        $control = new NivController();
         echo   $control->CargaFolio();
    }
    if(isset($_POST["Dependencias"])) {
        $control = new NivController();
         echo   $control->CargaDependencias();
    }
    if(isset($_POST["Corporacion"])) {
        $control = new NivController();
         echo   $control->CargaCorporacion();
    }
    if(isset($_POST["Municipio"])) {
        $control = new NivController();
         echo   $control->CargaMunicipios();
    }
    if(isset($_POST["Siti"])) {
        $control = new NivController();
         echo   $control->CargaSitio();
    }
    if(isset($_POST["Turnado"])) {
        $control = new NivController();
         echo   $control->TurnadoA();
    }
    if(isset($_POST["marcax"])){
        $Marca =$_POST["marcax"];
        $submarca = $_POST["submarca"];
        $clase =$_POST["clase"];
        $tipo =$_POST["tipo"];
        $fabrica =$_POST["fabrica"];
        $pais =$_POST["pais"];
        $nivSelect =$_POST["nivselect"];
        $IdNiv = $_POST["IdNiv"];
        $IdUsuario = $_POST["IdUsaurio"];
        $control = new NivController();
        return   $control->InsertarDatosNIV($Marca,$submarca,$clase,$tipo,$fabrica,$pais,$nivSelect,$IdNiv,$IdUsuario);
        
    }
    if(isset($_POST["Catalogo"]) && isset($_POST["IdMarca"]) && isset($_POST["datos"]) ) {
            include '../../models/NivsModel/nivModel.php';
            return NivModel::InsertarCatalogo($_POST["Catalogo"] ,$_POST["IdMarca"] ,$_POST["datos"]);
    }
    if(isset($_POST["IdNiv2"]) ) {
        include '../../models/NivsModel/nivModel.php';
        return NivModel::CambiarEstatus($_POST["IdNiv2"] );

    }           
    ?>
```

La función de **actualizarFila** la había agregado porque pensé que serviría de algo si añadía algo con qué identificar la fila que quiero que se actualice.

Si sirve de algo, dejaré estás imágenes por aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La **Respuesta del servidor** son los datos de opciones múltiples que mencioné.

Comment: **Los comentarios han sido [movidos al chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151104/discussion-on-question-by-adolph-nieto-realizar-un-update-de-base-de-datos-desde); por favor, no continuar la discusión aquí.** Antes de publicar un comentario bajo este, por favor revisa los [propósitos de los comentarios](/help/privileges/comment). Los comentarios que no pidan clarificaciones o sugieran mejoras normalmente deben ser publicados como una [respuesta](/help/how-to-answer), en [meta], o en el [chat]. Los comentarios que continúen la discusión podrán ser eliminados.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, el `try ... catch` debe ir en el método `actualizarFila`, pues es ahí donde puede levantarse la Excepción. Además, faltan controles en ese método. Lo haremos usando una variable de salida `$outPut`, e incluiremos un bloque `finally` para devolver el resultado de dicha variable desde ahí, sea cual sea.

### Función `actualizarFila`

Este sería el código:

```
public static function actualizarFila($folio, $EdicionNombre, $EdicionFechaDoc,$EdicionCorporacion, $EdicionFechaRegistro,
    $EdicionDocumento, $EdicionDocumentoRecibido, $EdicionFechadeRegistro, $EdicionDependencia, $EdicionMunicipio, $EdicionSite, 
    $EdicionTurnadoA, $EdicionObservaciones) 
{
    try 
    {
        include '../../../config/conexion.php';
        $consulta = "UPDATE OprCorrespodencia 
        SET Nombre = :EdicionNombre, FechaDocuemntoRecibido = :EdicionFechaDoc, Corporacion = :EdicionCorporacion, 
        FechaRegistro = :EdicionFechaRegistro, Documento = :EdicionDocumento, DocumentoRecibido = :EdicionDocumentoRecibido,
        FechadeRegistro = :EdicionFechadeRegistro, Dependencia = :EdicionDependencia, Municipio = :EdicionMunicipio, 
        Site = :EdicionSite, TurnadoA = :EdicionTurnadoA, Observaciones = :EdicionObservaciones WHERE folio = :folio";
        
        $stmt = $connect->prepare($consulta);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionNombre', $EdicionNombre, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionFechaDoc', $EdicionFechaDoc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionCorporacion', $EdicionCorporacion, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionFechaRegistro', $EdicionFechaRegistro, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionDocumento', $EdicionDocumento, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionDocumentoRecibido', $EdicionDocumentoRecibido, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionFechadeRegistro', $EdicionFechadeRegistro, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionDependencia', $EdicionDependencia, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionMunicipio', $EdicionMunicipio, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionSite', $EdicionSite, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionTurnadoA', $EdicionTurnadoA, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
        $stmt->bindParam(':EdicionObservaciones', $EdicionObservaciones, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
        $stmt->bindParam(':folio', $folio, PDO::PARAM_STR);     
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->rowCount()>0) 
        {
            $outPut=array('status'=>true, 'msg'=>sprintf('Filas actualizadas: %d',$stmt->rowCount()));
        } 
        else 
        {
            $outPut=array('status'=>false, 'msg'=>"No hubo error de código, pero el criterio $folio no se cumple");
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        $outPut=array('status'=>false, 'msg'=>sprintf('Error!: %s',$stmt->errorInfo()[2]));
    } 
    finally 
    {
        return $outPut;
    }
}
```

### Controlador

Poniendo el `try ... catch` donde debe ir, el código del controlador quedará más limpio. Necesitarás controlar solamente los valores. Usaremos para ello fusión de null. Cabe decir que deberías someter a evaluación todos los valores de aquellas columnas que tengan restricción `NOT NULL` en tu tabla, y que no asuman un valor por defecto, así evitarás que se intenten actualizar datos con valores nulos o pasados en blanco desde el cliente. Dado que eso no puedo adivinarlo, ese control no está reflejado en el código, puedes ponerlo con un `if` que verifique todas esas variables que no admiten nulos.

Otra cosa que no se entiende ahí es por qué obtienes la variable `$filaOriginal`¿ ?

Sea como sea, el código sería así, no está metido en ningún método, ponlo donde deba ir.

```
$isUpdate=$_POST['actualizarDatos'] ?? NULL;
if ($isUpdate)
{
    if (strpos(file_get_contents('php://input'), 'niv: 1') !== false) {
    // Manejar caso especial si 'niv: 1' está presente
        // Obtener datos del formulario
        $EdicionNombre = $_POST['NombreE'] ?? NULL;
        $EdicionFechaDoc = $_POST['FechaDocE'] ?? NULL;
        $EdicionCorporacion = $_POST['CorporacionE'] ?? NULL;
        $EdicionFechaRegistro = $_POST['FechaRegistroE'] ?? NULL;
        $EdicionDocumento = $_POST['DocumentoE'] ?? NULL;
        $EdicionDocumentoRecibido = $_POST['DocumentoRecibidoE'] ?? NULL;
        $EdicionFechadeRegistro = $_POST['FechadeRegistroE'] ?? NULL;
        $EdicionDependencia = $_POST['DependenciaE'] ?? NULL;
        $EdicionMunicipio = $_POST['MunicipioE'] ?? NULL;
        $EdicionSite = $_POST['SiteE'] ?? NULL;
        $EdicionTurnadoA = $_POST['TurnadoAE'] ?? NULL;
        $EdicionObservaciones = $_POST['ObservacionesE'] ?? NULL;
        $folio = $_POST['folio'] ?? NULL;
    // Si todos los datos son válidos, intentar actualizar
        require_once '../../models/NivsModel/nivModel.php';

        // Realizar la actualización en la base de datos
        $outPut = NivModel::actualizarFila($EdicionNombre, $EdicionFechaDoc, $EdicionCorporacion, $EdicionFechaRegistro,
        $EdicionDocumento, $EdicionDocumentoRecibido, $EdicionFechadeRegistro, $EdicionDependencia, $EdicionMunicipio, $EdicionSite,
        $EdicionTurnadoA, $EdicionObservaciones, $folio);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $outPut=array('status'=>false, 'msg'=>'niv 1 no está presente');    
    }
    
}
else
{
    $outPut=array('status'=>false, 'msg'=>'No se eligió la opción de actualizar');
}

header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($outPut);
exit();
```

### En el cliente

Finalmente, en Ajax, si observas la estructura de `$outPut` en el código de servidor, verás que implementamos una convención según la cual, cuando se hayan actualizado filas, la clave `status` de la respuesta será `true`, en caso contrario será `false`, y siempre habrá un mensaje bajo la clave `msg`. Ten en cuenta que puede ocurrir un caso de filas no encontradas por ejemplo. Ese no es un caso de error (de código) pero sí de lógica. Por eso, en consultas del tipo `INSERT`, `UPDATE` y `DELETE` se deben evaluar las filas afectadas, cosa que hicimos en la función.

Como decía, siguiendo la convención adoptada en `$outPut`, debes corregir la parte del `success`, en la cual, además, no se entiende por qué haces esto: `if (data && data) {` ¿?. Ahora, `data` tendrá dos claves, una llamada `status` que será `true` o `false` y una clave `msg` con un texto informativo.

```
success: function(data) {
  console.log("Respuesta completa del servidor:", data);
  if (data.status) {
    alert("Datos actualizados correctamente", data.msg);
      $("#Edición").modal("hide");
      table.ajax.reload(); // Recargar la tabla
  } else {
      alert("No fue posible actualizar los datos. "+data.msg);
      console.log("Mensajes de error:", data.msg);
  }
},
```

Comment: Agradezco que te hayas tomado el tiempo de poder ayudarme, realicé todos los cambios que mencionaste pero aún sigue sin realizar ninguna edición en mi base de datos, es más, en consola, la única respuesta que obtengo es **Mensajes de error: undefined** y, aparentemente, el contenido de data está vacío; sinceramente ya no sé a qué más moverle porque en esto llevo estancado más del mes :/
Una vez más, gracias por responder :)

Comment: @AdolphNieto actualizaste la parte del `success` como te dije (al final de la respuesta), observa que yo lo puse así, acorde con el código de servidor: **`console.log("Mensajes de error:", data.msg);`**. Por favor, actualiza tu pregunta poniendo el código como lo tienes ahora para revisarlo. Si el código del controlador está en una función pon la función completa.

Comment: @AdolphNieto revisa también si no hay más errores en la consola del navegador, tipo errores 500, ó 404, ó 403 u otros.